# Finding keywords in string[] getting results to a list

Tags: c#, linq, search, contains

I have a `string[]` containing ie:

```
abcd

Saving C:\\xx 

aacd

Saving C:\\yy

aecd

Saving C:\\zz 

and so on
```

Is there a way in linq that searches all the lines and returns only `C:\\xx`, `C:\\yy` and `C:\\zz` to a list/array.

This is what i tried so far:

```
string[] line = result.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' });
string searchTerms = "Saving ";

var results = (from comp in line.ToString()
               where searchTerms.All(s => comp.Contains(s))
               select comp).ToList();
```

Comment: You should remove the `ToString` so you'll iterate the values in your array instead of the characters in the name of the type of the array `System.String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `All` method, you can just use:

```
where comp.StartsWith(searchTerms)
```

And instead of splitting on `\r` and `\n` it's better to use:

```
string[] line = result.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

And you should also **remove ToString** from `line.ToString()`

```
var results = (from comp in line
               where comp.StartsWith(searchTerms)
               select comp).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice one thanks how do i omit Saving easily using that expression also?

Answer (score 0):

I don't, really understand your kind of input data, but if it is like this

```
string[] str = new string[] { "abcd", "Saving C:\\xx", "aacd", "Saving C:\\yy", "aecd", "Saving C:\\zz"};
```

then you can do the following:

```
List<string> result = str.Where(s => s.StartsWith("Saving C:\\")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If string ends path:

```
        string result = @"abcd
Saving C:\xx 
aacd
Saving C:\yy
aecd
Saving C:\zz 
and so on";

            string[] line = result.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' });
            string searchTerms = "Saving ";
            var lst = line.Where(x => x.StartsWith(searchTerms))
                .Select(y => y.Substring(searchTerms.Length));
            foreach (var x in lst)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
```

http://ideone.com/OXDMO5

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get the paths from a string you can use regular expressions for this:

```
var result = "abcd\r\nSaving C:\\xx\r\naacd\r\nSaving C:\\yy\r\naecd\r\nSaving C:\\zz\r\n";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=Saving )(.*)");
var matches = regex.Matches(result).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m).ToList();
```

**Edit**

Another more generic form of regular expression you can use to get *all* paths (not just the ones with `Saving`before them):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(result, ".:\\\\(.*?)(?=\s.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m).ToList();
```

This also removes any whitespace after the paths.

**Edit 2**

To also get paths within quotes (paths with spaces) you can use this regular expression:

```
var regex = new Regex("((\"\\w|\\w):\\\\)((.*\")|(.*?)(?=\\s.*))");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a simple IEnumerable containing each path.

**NOTE:** This will only return the part of each line *after* whatever is in `searchTerms`.

```
var result = 
      line.Where(l => l.StartsWith(searchTerms))
          .Select(c => new string(c.Skip(searchTerms.Count()).ToArray()));
```